# How to do system validation/verification tests for power window switches with anti pinch function, remote key door lock, smartphone control

Tags: power, window, switches

I am planning to write test specifications for verification, validation
of power window switches:

- driver side: auto up/down, manual up/down, door lock, window lock
- passenger, rear right , rear left: window up/down switches

One low-end variant  has anti-pinch for only driver side window, and the high-end variant has all doors with anti-pinch function.

The customer has various system requirements.

I would like to know test method, test setup to test the switches requirements in real car environment.

I am also interested in understanding various ways to break the system testing with negative test cases.

Let me know if any more information is required. I would gladly share it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm not sure if this question is within the site's scope

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might be a better fit on the QA.SE site

Comment: There is a "flesh" standard which is just a polymer bar with a certain durometer which is used to test the "pinch" function.  Obstensibly it simulates an infant's arm. Check the SAE J-spec database.

Comment: Thanks Steve, can you please point out JXXXX code to find out which standard it is.